# How do I fix LNK2019 errors after adding libpng to a VS2019 C++ project through Nuget?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, libpng

I am creating a solution that requires the use of libpng. I installed this library and its dependencies through Visual Studio 2019's Nuget Package Manager, and including <png.h> and using functions and macros from the library does not lead to errors. However, should I try building the solution, I get one LNK2019 error per every reference to the library function or variable. It seems to me that NuGet failed to add the library locations to the linker properties. I have found where are the .lib files located, but I'm lost as to which settings do I adjust so that the Studio looks for, and finds, these files in the NuGet directory.

Comment: To add the link files, go to Project Properties -> Linker -> Inputs -> Additional Dependencies and add the library files in there.

Comment: @D-RAJ thank you, I tried that as well. I added libpng16.* and zlib.* *.lib and *.dll files to Additional Dependencies, but now I'm getting LNK1104: "cannot open file libpng16.lib". It could be suggested that I should copy these files directly to my project directory, but do I have to replace these files every time I change my build configuration, say, between Debug x64 and Release x64?

Comment: UPD: linking *.dll was not necessary (in fact, it caused LNK1107). I copied the *.lib files to the project directory, and found out how to link against different *.lib files in Debug and Release configurations, but this isn't the exact solution I was looking for. Is it possible to get Visual Studio to look for these files in the directories NuGet puts them in? This workaround is only viable because I don't use many packages in this specific project.

Comment: The linker cannot search for the library file in every directory. So we need to specify it. You have two options for this. 1) Add the full file path to the Additional Dependencies tab (ie: `C:\Libs\library.lib`). 2) Add the folder path where the linker should find the libraries in. You can do this by adding the file path in Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories (ie: `C:\Libs\`).

Comment: Didn't occur to me that you could specify folders instead of files in Additional Dependencies. Thank you!

Comment: @Shadow97 To not leave this question in an unanswered state, please write an answer to your own question and describe what you did (just as you did with the question you asked after this one). It may help other people in the future.

Comment: I ended up not using the nuget version of libpng due to exceptions I've been catching on calls to `png_write_png()`, so I thought I did something wrong and opted to avoid posting a potentially misleading answer. Though it is true that it helped me fix the specific issue the question was about, even if Perry's answer is a cleaner solution for my specific case. @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue why the automatic nuget cannot add the lib dependencies into the **Linker** is that the c++ nuget is for `v140` and `v120` build tool. And if your project is created by **VS2019**, VS uses `v142` build tool(for **VS2019**) by default.

You can check the `targets` file(Methods to import lib automatically) from the nuget package `<solution_folder>\packages\libpng.1.6.28.1\build\native\libpng.targets`.

[image]

[image]

**So** this file cannot find `V140` and `V120`,(your VS2019 uses `V142`) make the condition to false, so that auto import lib fails forever. That is the reason.

**V140** is `VC++2015 build tool` while **V120** is `VC++ 2013 build tool`.

If your PC has installed **VS2015** and **VS2013**, you can change build tool for VS0219 by right-click on the project **Properties**-->**Configuration Properties**-->**General**--> change **Platfrom Toolset** to Visual Studio 2015(v140).

[image]

## For a better solution

**And if your PC only has VS2019 and also for a better workaround,**

You should install [libpng-v142](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libpng-v142/1.6.37.2?_src=template) nuget package **instead** and it is for **VS2019 VC++**.

Comment: I built the lib with platform v143 and it still says unresolved external symbols in my project that also uses platform v143